# How to test Unity projects with Travis CI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sh, travis-ci

I was following this specific guide: https://jonathan.porta.codes/2015/04/17/automatically-build-your-unity3d-project-in-the-cloud-using-travisci-for-free/ to test my unity project with travis CI but have been running into the same problem and don't understand how to change the 'installer' program to fix this problem:

```
$ ./Scripts/install.sh
Downloading from     http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/a6d8d714de6f/MacEditorInstaller/    Unity-5.4.0f3.pkg:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left Speed
100 16433  100 16433    0     0  16498      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16498
Installing Unity.pkg
installer: Error the package path specified was invalid: 'Unity.pkg'.
The command "./Scripts/install.sh" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Here are the scripts I wrote using the tutorial:
.travis.yml

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode61
rvm:
- 2.1.2
install:
- ./Scripts/install.sh
script:
- ./Scripts/build.sh
```

install.sh
    #! /bin/sh

```
echo 'Downloading from http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/a6d8d714de6f/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.4.0f3.pkg:



curl -o Unity.pkg http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/a6d8d714de6f/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.4.0f3.pkg:

echo 'Installing Unity.pkg'
sudo installer -dumplog -package Unity.pkg -target /
```

Any help for this problem or guidance towards a solution would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: `http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/a6d8d714de6f/MacEd` is a 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon at the end of the url inside `install.sh`

```
curl -o Unity.pkg http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/a6d8d714de6f/MacEditorInstaller/Unity-5.4.0f3.pkg:

Unity-5.4.0f3.pkg:  => Unity-5.4.0f3.pkg
```